# Agora API Addview function in Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, agora.io

I'm trying to use Agora API

every thing works good but Addview function in my Javascript that create container to see my webcam doesn't work

I call it after listening to "stream-subscribed" Event but it doesn't work.

I figured out that it doesn't listen to "stream-added" event I don't know why>

please note:

I added App_ID
I added Channel Name
I added Token

Thanks for help

My Javescript file

```
// rtc object
var rtc = {
    client: null,
    joined: false,
    published: false,
    localStream: null,
    remoteStreams: [],
    params: {}
  };

  // Options for joining a channel
  var option = {
    appID: "MY_APP_ID",
    channel: "MY_Channel_Name",
    uid: null,
    token: "Channel_Token"
  }

  $('#create').click(function() {


    // Create a client
    rtc.client = AgoraRTC.createClient({mode: "live", codec: "h264"});

    // Initialize the client
    rtc.client.init(option.appID, function () {
    console.log("init success");
        // The value of role can be "host" or "audience".
        rtc.client.setClientRole("host"); 
    // Join a channel
        rtc.client.join(option.token ? option.token : null, option.channel, option.uid ? +option.uid : null, function (uid) {
            console.log("join channel: " + option.channel + " success, uid: " + uid);
            rtc.params.uid = uid;
            // Create a local stream
            rtc.localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
                streamID: rtc.params.uid,
                audio: true,
                video: true,
                screen: false,
            })
            // Initialize the local stream
            rtc.localStream.init(function () {
                console.log("init local stream success");
                // Publish the local stream
                rtc.client.publish(rtc.localStream, function (err) {
                    console.log("publish failed");
                    console.error(err);
                })

                rtc.client.on("stream-added", function (evt) {  
                    var remoteStream = evt.stream;
                    var id = remoteStream.getId();
                    if (id !== rtc.params.uid) {
                    rtc.client.subscribe(remoteStream, function (err) {
                        console.log("stream subscribe failed", err);
                    })
                    }
                    console.log('stream-added remote-uid: ', id);
                });
                rtc.client.on("stream-subscribed", function (evt) {
                    var remoteStream = evt.stream;
                    var id = remoteStream.getId();
                    // Add a view for the remote stream.
                    addView(id);
                    // Play the remote stream.
                    remoteStream.play("remote_video_" + id);
                    console.log('stream-subscribed remote-uid: ', id);
                })
            }, function (err) {
                console.error("init local stream failed ", err);
            })
        }, function(err) {
            console.error("client join failed", err)
        })
    }, (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    });

});

$('#leave').click(function() {


// Leave the channel
    rtc.client.leave(function () {
        // Stop playing the local stream
        rtc.localStream.stop();
        // Close the local stream
        rtc.localStream.close();
        // Stop playing the remote streams and remove the views
        while (rtc.remoteStreams.length > 0) {
        var stream = rtc.remoteStreams.shift();
        var id = stream.getId();
        stream.stop();
        removeView(id);
        }
        console.log("client leaves channel success");
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("channel leave failed");
        console.error(err);
    })
});
function addView (id, show) {
    if (!$("#" + id)[0]) {
      $("<div/>", {
        id: "remote_video_panel_" + id,
        class: "video-view",
      }).appendTo("#video");
      $("<div/>", {
        id: "remote_video_" + id,
        class: "video-placeholder",
      }).appendTo("#remote_video_panel_" + id);
      $("<div/>", {
        id: "remote_video_info_" + id,
        class: "video-profile " + (show ? "" :  "hide"),
      }).appendTo("#remote_video_panel_" + id);
      $("<div/>", {
        id: "video_autoplay_"+ id,
        class: "autoplay-fallback hide",
      }).appendTo("#remote_video_panel_" + id);
    }
  }
  function removeView (id) {
    if ($("#remote_video_panel_" + id)[0]) {
      $("#remote_video_panel_"+id).remove();
    }
  }
```

My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Basic Live Broadcast</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/common.css" />
</head>
<body>
<button id="create"> create</button>
<button id="leave">leave</button>



<script src="/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/agora-rtc-sdk/AgoraRTCSDK.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/agora_ver4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your event callbacks outside of the join channel success. The client callbacks need to happen within the same block as the client initialization.

By waiting for the joinChannel success, it's too late and the engine fired off the event before your listener was added.

using your JS code above, it should look like this:

```
// rtc object
var rtc = {
  client: null,
  joined: false,
  published: false,
  localStream: null,
  remoteStreams: [],
  params: {}
};

// Options for joining a channel
var option = {
  appID: "MY_APP_ID",
  channel: "MY_Channel_Name",
  uid: null,
  token: "Channel_Token"
}

$('#create').click(function() {


  // Create a client
  rtc.client = AgoraRTC.createClient({
    mode: "live",
    codec: "h264"
  });

  // Initialize the client
  rtc.client.init(option.appID, function() {
    console.log("init success");
    // The value of role can be "host" or "audience".
    rtc.client.setClientRole("host");

    // define callbacks before joining the channel
    rtc.client.on("stream-added", function(evt) {
      var remoteStream = evt.stream;
      var id = remoteStream.getId();
      if (id !== rtc.params.uid) {
        rtc.client.subscribe(remoteStream, function(err) {
          console.log("stream subscribe failed", err);
        })
      }
      console.log('stream-added remote-uid: ', id);
    });
    rtc.client.on("stream-subscribed", function(evt) {
      var remoteStream = evt.stream;
      var id = remoteStream.getId();
      // Add a view for the remote stream.
      addView(id);
      // Play the remote stream.
      remoteStream.play("remote_video_" + id);
      console.log('stream-subscribed remote-uid: ', id);
    })

    // Join a channel
    rtc.client.join(option.token ? option.token : null, option.channel, option.uid ? +option.uid : null, function(uid) {
      console.log("join channel: " + option.channel + " success, uid: " + uid);
      rtc.params.uid = uid;
      // Create a local stream
      rtc.localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
        streamID: rtc.params.uid,
        audio: true,
        video: true,
        screen: false,
      })
      // Initialize the local stream
      rtc.localStream.init(function() {
        console.log("init local stream success");
        // Publish the local stream
        rtc.client.publish(rtc.localStream, function(err) {
          console.log("publish failed");
          console.error(err);
        })
      }, function(err) {
        console.error("init local stream failed ", err);
      })
    }, function(err) {
      console.error("client join failed", err)
    })
  }, (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });

});

$('#leave').click(function() {


  // Leave the channel
  rtc.client.leave(function() {
    // Stop playing the local stream
    rtc.localStream.stop();
    // Close the local stream
    rtc.localStream.close();
    // Stop playing the remote streams and remove the views
    while (rtc.remoteStreams.length > 0) {
      var stream = rtc.remoteStreams.shift();
      var id = stream.getId();
      stream.stop();
      removeView(id);
    }
    console.log("client leaves channel success");
  }, function(err) {
    console.log("channel leave failed");
    console.error(err);
  })
});

function addView(id, show) {
  if (!$("#" + id)[0]) {
    $("<div/>", {
      id: "remote_video_panel_" + id,
      class: "video-view",
    }).appendTo("#video");
    $("<div/>", {
      id: "remote_video_" + id,
      class: "video-placeholder",
    }).appendTo("#remote_video_panel_" + id);
    $("<div/>", {
      id: "remote_video_info_" + id,
      class: "video-profile " + (show ? "" : "hide"),
    }).appendTo("#remote_video_panel_" + id);
    $("<div/>", {
      id: "video_autoplay_" + id,
      class: "autoplay-fallback hide",
    }).appendTo("#remote_video_panel_" + id);
  }
}

function removeView(id) {
  if ($("#remote_video_panel_" + id)[0]) {
    $("#remote_video_panel_" + id).remove();
  }
}
```